# Passing a string from server.R to ui.R?

Tags: shiny

So I have shiny dashboard and I made the title clickable by modifying, but now I want to add a string, namely user_addition. How can I pass the string that I get from the session object to ui?

ui.R:

```
dbHeader$children[[2]]$children <-  tags$a(style='color: white;',
href = paste0("/?username=", textOutput("user_addition")) , "Website-name")
```

server.R

```
output$user_addition <- renderText({ parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)[['username']] })
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it can be helpful. The below code can be used to load the items from a data.frame (server.R) for instance and provide it as options for the user on ui.R.

```
library(shiny)
 
ui <- fluidPage(
      uiOutput("myOptions"),
      textOutput("myChoosenText")
)
 
server <- function(input, output, session) {    
 
      letter <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
 
      output$myOptions <- renderUI({
                selectInput("variable1", "Choose Option:", as.list(letter)) 
      })
 
      output$myChoosenText <- renderText({
      myChoice <- input$variable1
      })
}
 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```